# jQuery - Background-Position Animation Easing Not Working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation, jquery-animate

I'm trying to change the background-position of an image like an odometer. Everything seems to work other than the easing, it just changes in 'linear' other than 'swing'. Is very annoying, I've search high and low and have found nothing.

```
        col.animate({
            'background-position': '0 ' + ((newDigit * settings.heightNumber * -1) + zeroSet)
        }, 
        1000, 
        'swing');
      }
```

I also need this to work cross-browser. It does work cross-browser at present without easing.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you included the effects library from www.jqueryui.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"swing" is the default parameter. passing "swing" is like passing no parameter. you can use jquery ui which has a lot more easing styles.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html

Comment: All I want is the image to scroll up or down dependent on whether the counter is increment or decrement.

Comment: Not to worry. Found out that background-position can't be animated easily so have changed my mark-up to accommodate position: absolute and top to animate what I want. Thanks for your help tho.